# inbound sftp channel adapter custom filter not accepting same file again

Tags: spring-integration

I have very simple custom filter for inbound sftp channel adapter where I just check if file extension is in list of accepted or not. If so it returns true and should allow to process that file.

What is happening is first time that file is processed it works fine. if same file is dropped in my sftp server it comes to filter and it is returning true that means file is accepted still it does not put that message on the downstream queue. Here is my sample config looks like

```html
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapter"
   channel="ftpChannel"
   session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
   local-directory="c:\\temp"
   remote-directory="//test//inbound"
   remote-file-separator="/"
   auto-create-local-directory="true"
   delete-remote-files="true"

   filter="customfilter"
   preserve-timestamp="true"
   >
  
  <int:poller cron="0/5 * * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
 </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Did you try making preserve-timestamp="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is one more `FileListFilter` in the `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`:

```
private volatile FileListFilter<File> localFileListFilter = new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>();
```

Since you guarantee the `duplicate` logic with your `filter="customfilter"` you should configure `local-filter`:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapter"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            ....
            local-filter="acceptAllFileFilter"/>

<bean id="acceptAllFileFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter"/>
```

Comment: I have similar problem as the question has been asked. I tried your solution by configuring the local-filter and it goes to infinite loop (polling the remote file and creating the message payload but not sending it to the downstream service activator)

Comment: Sounds like a different story. Please, start a new SO thread.